# React Router: Creating pages dynamically from the Wordpress REST API

Tags: json, reactjs, react-router

I've created an array of elements that I've retrieved from the Wordpress REST API JSON object. I want to use react-router to make each element its own separate page using its **id** as the slug e.g. (/items/1).

I've hit a bit of a wall and haven't able to figure out how to dynamically create the routes using react-router. Any guidance would be much appreciated!!!

```
export default class ItemContainer extends React.Component {

  constructor(){
      super();
      this.state= {
        items: []
      }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
      var th = this;
      this.serverRequest =
      axios.get('http://website.com/wp-json/wp/v2/item/')
        .then(function(result) {
          th.setState({
          officers: result.data
        });
      })
    }

    componentWillUnmount(){
      this.serverRequest.abort();
    }


    render(){

      const ItemComponents = this.state.items.map((item) => {
        return <Item key={item.id} {...item} />;
      });


      return(
          <div className="item-wrapper">
            {ItemComponents}
          </div>
      );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach you probably want to take is to **not** create specific routes for each item and use a [param](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/Glossary.md#params) instead.

Your [path](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/RouteMatching.md#path-syntax) could look something like this:

```
<Route path="/items/:itemId" component={ItemPage} />
```

This will allow you to get the `itemId` in the `ItemPage` component and load the correct content. If you get a id that does not correspond to a valid item, redirect to an error page or any other page you like.

You can access the `itemId` param on the props of `ItemPage` like:

```
this.props.params.itemId
```

If you really feel you must have specific routes for each item, you will need to get your hands dirty with [Dynamic Routing](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/DynamicRouting.md).